# Pass vector elements to a function in c++

Tags: c++

I now have a vector of objects. And a pre-defined function that can take objects as parameters. Just curious if there's a way of passing these objects to this function?

```
std::vector<obj> objects; //contains obj1, obj2 .., objn
```

And I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
 foo(obj1, obj2 ... , objn) //foo can take as many objects as I want
```

Comment: The `std::vector` is an object in itself, you can pass in as a parameter and us it (access its elements) inside your function `foo`.

Comment: Nope. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: The idiomatic way to do this is to pass a pair of iterators to `foo`.

Comment: Check this link which shows how to declare a function with variable argumenta: https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson17.html

Comment: Each element can be passed by reference, using: `&objects[index]`.

Comment: @JorgeOmarMedra: that would be passing the elements by pointer, not by reference

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thaaaaat's correct! I got confused since i was thinking in the function argument. From http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/z6vU7k9E/ "A reference variable is a variable which 'refers to' another 
named or unnamed variable". As you said, This (`&objects[index]`) is how to get a Pointer from the object . Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

While common in scripted languages like P(ython|erl), this still requires a library solution in C++. Something like

```
template<typename F, class Container> inline decltype(auto) apply(F f, Container const &args) {
    switch(args.size()) {
        case 0: return f();
        case 1: return f(args.front());
        case 2: return f(args[0], args[1]);
        case 3: return f(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
        // and so forth
        default: throw std::range_error("f does not accept that many arguments!");
    }
}
```

Comment: There won't ever be a library that does this, argument count is decided at compile time, while containers are dynamic. The switch you've shown is also a compile error with a non variadic functor

Comment: Define variadic functor, please.

Answer (score 1):

Yes，in C++ 11 you can use a variadic template, like this:

```
template<typename ...Ts>
void f(Ts...args);
```

The following code is a working example:

```
#include <vector>

class obj {
public:
    obj(int _id) {id = _id; }
    int id;
};

std::vector<obj> objects;

template<typename ...Ts>
void f(Ts...args) 
{
    const int size = sizeof...(args);
    obj objs[size] = { args... };

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        objects.push_back(objs[i]);
}

int main()
{
    obj obj1(1), obj2(2), obj3(3);
    f(obj1, obj2, obj3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you change the `for` loop to a [range-for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), you don't need the `size` and `objs[]` local variables anymore: `for(auto && arg: { args... }) { objects.push_back(arg); }`. Otherwise, you could just get rid of the `for` loop altogether: `const obj objs[sizeof...(args)] = { args... }; objects.insert(objects.end(), std::begin(args), std::end(args));` alternatively `void f() {} template<typename ...Ts> void f(obj first, Ts... rest) { objects.push_back(first); f(rest...); }`

Comment: alternatively `void f(const std::initializer_list<obj> &args) { objects.insert(objects.end(), args.begin(), args.end()); }` then you can do `f({obj1, obj2, obj3});`

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks, this will make the code more concise.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is.

That being said, your `std::vector<obj>` also is an object though, and you can pass it as an argument to your function (indirectly passing its contents). For example, if you need to modify `obj1` or any other, you can write your function like so:

```
void foo(std::vector<obj>& p_objects)
{
    // Do something to obj1 and so on using p_objects.
}
```

If you don't need to modify `obj1` to `objn`, then use a `const` reference:

```
void foo(const std::vector<obj>& p_objects)
{
    // Do something to obj1 and so on using p_objects, 
    // but you can't modify anything!
}
```

I know it is not exactly what you are looking for, but it is a standard way to achieve something very similar (and to my opinion cleaner) in C++.